# Using cell text as file reference in nested sum if array formula in excel

Tags: excel, array-formulas, excel-indirect, nested-if

In excel, I'm using a nested sum if array formula:

```
=SUM(IF(('Filename'!$B$3:$B$25000=$C$1)*('Filename'!$C$3:$C$25000=$F$1)=1,'Filename'!$X$3:$X$25000,0))
```

Now I am using above sum if to extract data from multiple csv files which have similar structure only their name differs. Instead of writing the full file name for each formula I want to refer to filename by cell's text which has filename.

`INDIRECT` wont work if the referred file is closed.

What options do I have?

Answer (score 0):

If it's from a closed workbook you'll need to look at something like Harlan Grove's pull Function or Laurent Longre's MOREFUNC.XLL add in with INDIRECT.EXT which allows closed workbooks to be used.